# How does boost::split work?

Tags: c++, boost

Does the boost split function require copying the source string before split?

For example-

```
const char *c = "S1 S2 S3";
std::vector<std::string> v;
boost::split(v, c, boost::is_any_of(" "));
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just iterate over const cstring to find tokens and copy them to container?

Answer (score 1):

It works exactly like your code. No need to copy.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to copy, according to [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.split_hpp) it will make copies for you (you could also store references). There is no problems with `const` inputs thus.